# Dropwizard Rest API endpoint manipulation

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application to POST/GET query information. I have a `@POST` method that populates an arrayList with my query and its' 11 parameters. For brevity, I cut the example down to only show 3 parameters.

```
@Path("/query")
public class QueryResource

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
public List<Query> getQueries() {
    List<Query> queries = new ArrayList<Query>();
    logger.info("Calling get queries with {} method.");
    queries.add(new Query("b622d2c6-03b2-4488-9d5d-46814606e550", "eventTypeThing", "action"));
    return queries;
```

I can send a get request through ARC and it will return successful with a json representation of the query.

I run into issues when I try to make a `@GET` request on the specific `queryId` and return a specific parameter of it. As such,

```
@GET
@Path("/{queryId}/action")
public Response getAction(@PathParam("queryId") String queryId, @PathParam("action") String action){
    logger.info("Get action by queryId {}");
    String output = "Get action: " + action;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
```

On the rest client I make a get request to `https://localhost/query/b622d2c6-03b2-4488-9d5d-46814606e550/action`

I'm expecting that to return the action type of that specific `queryId`, but instead is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not declare "action" as a proper param in the @Path annotation of the method. You need to change that to:

```
@Path("/{queryId}/{action}")
```

Comment: I have read this elsewhere and made the fix. The get request is still returning as a null value.

Comment: I think I found the reason. There's an unexpected token returned within my response. It's sending JSON to the client when I believe the MIME type should be something different.